# SendMessage with TDM_CLICK_BUTTON return value is always zero

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage, taskdialog

In my C# application I'm trying to use the `TDM_CLICK_BUTTON` message to click a button in a TaskDialog. This basically works just fine. What I expect to happen, happens. I even receive the `TDN_BUTTON_CLICKED` notification.

But the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787499%28VS.85%29.aspx) says, that the return value of `SendMessage` would be nonzero if the call succeeds. But it always returns zero for me.

This is my code:

```
public void ClickButton( int buttonId ) {
  bool success = UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(
    WindowHandle,
    (uint)UnsafeNativeMethods.TASKDIALOG_MESSAGES.TDM_CLICK_BUTTON,
    (IntPtr)buttonId,
    IntPtr.Zero ) != IntPtr.Zero;
  if( !success ) {
    int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    throw new Win32Exception( lastWin32Error, "SendMessage for TDM_CLICK_BUTTON failed." );
  }
}
```

`lastWin32Error` is always zero when the exception is thrown. Which would be another indicator that everything is fine.

`SendMessage` is declared in my code like this:

```
[DllImport( "user32.dll", SetLastError = true )]
internal static extern IntPtr SendMessage( IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam );
```

Is the documentation incorrect or am I using the message incorrectly?

Comment: Not an answer, but you need to add  `SetLastError=true` to your DllImport for `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` to work correctly.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I added that, but lastWin32Error still remains 0.

Comment: If I would go by the documentation, no, it doesn't. The return value is zero. But what I intended to do with the call (invoke the action that would happen if a certain button was clicked) succeeds. I even get the TDN_BUTTON_CLICKED notification. Which is the basis for my whole confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took the C++ Windows SDK TaskDialog sample and tried this message out in there as well. The return value of `SendMessage` remains zero always.

I noticed that a `TDN_BUTTON_CLICKED` notification will always be sent (even if the button id does not exist). If the button exists or not has no effect on the `SendMessage` return value.

Then I suspected, that the return value for that notification might have an effect, but no matter what I return from the callback (`TRUE/FALSE/S_OK/42`), my `SendMessage` return value remains zero.

So, given that I found no way to make this fail and/or return a nonzero value, I can only assume that the documentation is incorrect.

edit: I got a reply to my documentation feedback I sent a few days ago. Turns out the documentation is indeed incorrect. The return value is to be ignored.